# Sending JSON formatted data to a SOAP endpoint (WSDL)

Tags: json, web-services, soap, wsdl

Is it possible to send an API call in the format of "application/json" to a SOAP endpoint?

When working with JSON, I know we typically work with REST services.  But due to limitations on the customer's side, they cannot send a typical SOAP envelope (XML, name/value pairs), instead, they can only send JSON data to a WSDL service.

I do not know of the customer's development environment yet (I have an email out to them) which this API call is being made from.

Comment: SOAP requires SOAP. Period. Maybe the same service has a JSON endpoint. If it does, then you wouldn't send SOAP to the JSON endpoint. Ask the owner of the service.

Comment: Alternatively, you could create an intermediate service that accepts JSON and sends SOAP, then accepts the SOAP response and replies with JSON to the original JSON request. It would be a use of "[The Adapter Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern)"

Comment: Unless they are using Turbo C or Turbo Pascal I find it hard to believe that they cannot send a SOAP request. It was easy to do in VB6 days already and that is pre-history. Like John said you cannot send JSON to a SOAP service.

Comment: It's possible.  I've done it by building message formatters that reside on the client, server, or a proxy server.  I believe [Apache Synapse](http://synapse.apache.org/index.html) does something similar [example](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB451/Sample+440%3A+Exposing+a+SOAP+Service+Over+JSON) "JSON client will send a stockquote request to Synapse using the JSON content interchange format. Synapse will trnasform it into a SOAP request and forward to the Axis2 server."